# One terminal app; two (Favorites) launch modes

Tags: command-line, launcher, customization, dock, favorites

Running Ubuntu 20.04, I wish to have two clickable launch modes for `gnome-terminal` in the Favorites bar [i.e. in the "Dock"]. For example, I want both the default launch and a bespoke launch. The default launcher was trivial to add to the Favorites bar, using the well-known mechanisms. For the custom launcher, I created the following `.desktop` file:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/custom-terminal.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=CustomTerminal
Comment=Terminal for Specialized Development
Exec=$HOME/.bin/custom-terminal.sh
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/gnome-terminal.png
Terminal=false
```

For the bespoke launch, I set an environment variable (`FOOBAR`) by which my `~/.bashrc` file can invoke custom logic:

```
$ cat $HOME/.bin/custom-terminal.sh
#!/bin/bash
FOOBAR=SomeTriggerValue /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

PROBLEM: I can add the custom launcher to the Favorites bar, but the launched instance is incorrectly associated to the default launcher's icon. i.e. The default launcher's icon [in the Favorites bar] gets the "red dot" for my custom instance of `gnome-terminal`.

I have tried making copies of the executable [of course, having different paths] to "fool" the desktop into believing that the one app is actually two, but that gimmick failed.

I noticed that if I right-click on the default `gnome-terminal` icon, then I'm offered a `Preferences` option. A right-click on the custom `gnome-terminal` icon does not offer a `Preferences` option.

QUESTION: How to add 2+ custom launchers for `gnome-terminal` to the Favorites bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu launcher distinguishes running applications based on the WMClass. You should do two things

- ensure that the terminal from the custom launcher adopts a different WM_CLASS than the default.
- declare that custom WM_CLASS in the launcher using a `StartupWMClass=` directive.

See `gnome-terminal --help-gtk` for the option on how to set your own WM_CLASS.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer helped, then please consider "accepting" it, i.e., click the checkmark next to the question. This helps future users.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay. I asked myself, "How to 'accept' this answer?"